# How to set specific GOPATH?

Tags: ubuntu, go, ubuntu-12.04

I have my go installed with ubuntu package.
Basics library (fmt etc.) are working correctly.

But I have a real project in /var/www/mygoproject with multiple subfolder ex:

- ./subfolder1
- ./lib1
- ./lib2
- ./subfolder2

subfolderX contain different go applications and libX contain shared code.

I would like, in subfolderX use 
import "lib1/package-inside"
but I always get the  `imported and not used` error.

What I have to do ?

---

edit:
code of /var/www/project/subproject/folder/alpha.go

```
package main

import (
    "subprojectA/folder/apackage" //doesnt work
    "./apackage" //works but not the cleanest
)

func main() {

    var sr interface{}
    sr = "tmp"

    apackage.Run(sr)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The go build system, in the first approximation, resolves import path `pth` by looking for package named `$(basename pth)` in directory `$GOPATH/src/pth`.

It seems to me you're missing the `/src/` part.

Useful discussion of GOPATH can be found eg. [here](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/), another [here](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#tmp_3)

Comment: I thought I can dodge the /src/ part but it seems I cannot. I rebuild folder with /src/ and /pkg/ subfolder and put all my code in ./src/. then it works